# Css having trouble aligning image with text horizontally

Tags: html, css, image, center, vertical-alignment

I'm having touble aligning my text horizontally with my image... It's actually aligned horizontally, but the image creates the illusion that it's not.

[image: problem]

Code(CSS):

```
/* Copyright © 2016 Dynavio Cooperative */
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
    box-shadow:  0 1px 2px #000000;
}
.nav-logo {
    width: 130px;
    height: 58px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.nav-items {
    display: inline-block;
}
.nav-item {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: SinkinSansRegular;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Code(HTML):

```
<div class="navbar">
<img src="../images/logo.png" class="nav-logo">
<ul class="nav-items">
<li class="nav-item">Homepage</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ha91bzsu/

Comment: From what I can think you need the same font as that you see in the text image. Try using bold text, it could also solve your problem

Comment: please post a live demo with the actual image (e.g. jsfiddle.net)

Comment: the bottom of dynav seems aligned with homepage text, how exactly you want it aligned?

Comment: The H should be aligned with the blue io

Comment: it's only an illution. If you want it to look aligned horizontal then it wont be. in your case if you want it to look correct you have to add padding to the `.nav-items` or make things `block` and float

Comment: Posted a dynamic solution for you, as any trick using fixed values will mess up between browsers, as they render fonts slightly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `vertical-align: middle; padding: 0;` to your `.nav-items` rule and you'll get an equivalent result across browsers

Stack snippet

```css
/* Copyright © 2016 Dynavio Cooperative */
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
  box-shadow:  0 1px 2px #000000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.nav-logo {
  width: 130px;
  height: 58px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.nav-items {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <img src="http://87.92.41.2/logo.png" class="nav-logo">
  <ul class="nav-items">
    <li class="nav-item">Homepage</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1:**

1. modify `vertical-align: middle;` property of `.nav-logo` to `vertical-align: top;`
2. add a property `margin-top: 17px;` to the `.nav-items`. You can adjust this margin and text height property upto your satisfaction.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sajibche/twpy8eq8/

**Approach 2**

Another dynamic solution: 
Just use `vertical-align: bottom;` for both `.nav-logo` and `.nav-items` elements.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sajibche/cd52ytch/

Comment: fiddle added in ans.

Comment: This answer/fiddle does center it (in Chrome), though may I suggest you don't use fixed values like this, as it will render different across browsers (if chosen font is missing, even worse misalignment can occur) and extra adjustment is most likely needed when change font size/family/weight.

Comment: @LGSon added a dynamic solution.

Comment: 2:nd approach much better

Answer (score 0):

Try using the line height property of CSS on the text

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

If that doesn't work, try small adjustments using margin or padding.

Comment: Usually text elements (h1, h2, p, etc) have pre established margins or paddings, use the inspector on your web browser to see if they have that attribute and zero it, should do the trick then

Answer (score 0):

You would have to put `display: block;` in order to make it work. Then you can controll the padding and margin. Note: add a clearfix class to your navbar also.

[updated jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ha91bzsu/3/)

```
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.nav-logo {
  width: 130px;
  height: 58px;
  line-height: 58px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.nav-items {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 58px;
  line-height: 58px;
  padding: 4px 0 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: aqua;
}
```